# How to connect azure synapse and an enterprise git repo using personal access token?

Tags: azure, github, azure-synapse, azure-git-deployment

Im trying to link my git repo to an azure synapse sandbox and Im facing this error

```
Failed to list GitHub repositories. Please make sure account name is correct and you have permission to perform the action.
```

Im using a personal access token, an enterprise git account, and full repo access for the token.

[image]

Could someone please point what I maybe missing. Does it require any permission on the azure side as well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Configure a Repository**

**Go** to ***GitHub*** -> open code and ***copy HTTPS Link*** use this link to ***GitHub enterprise URL Login*** on synapse -> Creating a [**personal access token**](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) on GitHub -> connect to GitHub.

[image: Ref1]
[image: ref1]

***Creating a personal access token***

[image: ref2]

[image: ref5]
[image: ref6]

**Reference**:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/admin/configuration/repositories/github-enterprise/

Comment: Hei thanks for answering. I had done the same way, problem was i was so dump to put the whole profile link in the GitHub owner field. It required only my profile I'd and not the complete link.

Answer (score 3):

In the GitHub repository owner, only give the owner name. Eg johny, instead of GitHub.com/johny

Comment: This was my issue! They need to make this more obvious or just work both ways. Silly.